# Any downside of using GUID as the file name of uploaded images

Tags: guid, image-uploading

Is there any downside of using GUID as a file name an นด uploaded image to avoid duplication ?

Answer (score 1):

Your filenames will be unique, true. But there won't be any way to sort them, in any order.

You could use the [**Unix TimeStamp**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in front of your GUID, to help sort-by-name and perform other such operations, without having to use a look-up table in your database.

Answer (score 1):

If you store uploaded files with a name based on the hash (eg. SHA1) of the file contents, then you can *also* store files with identical contents only once (saving space).

Answer (score 0):

I think its enough unique, but consider using an own generator using a date and time and some serial number, i think the names would be more expressive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a downside to using GUIDs in a filename. CLSID's are GUIDs, and some virus scanners will think that you are trying to use this exploit, and will mark your files as potential malware.

See [Microsoft Windows CLSID Hidden File Extension Vulnerability](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/viewAlert.x?alertId=2104) for more information.